# How can I avoid my overflow text disappears in DIV height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm practicing flexbox and tried to build a simple dialog box with some text inside a div. Ok..

Everything was going on troubleless.. But when I put some example text inside my message div, it starts to seem smaller than the overflowed text.

I tried to set some adjusts.. But nothing seems to work...

```
#areaMsg {
    width:86%;
    float:right;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    overflow:auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background:yellow;
}
```

Look whats going on here:

[LINK IN FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rj27p2rd/)

https://jsfiddle.net/rj27p2rd/

P.s: Note that lines 1, 2 and 3 is completely hidden.. And line 4 is truncated.

Comment: Remove `align-items: center;`

Comment: FYI, don't use `//`  comments in CSS, they will mess up the rules

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody! The // comment were used just in fiddle example! I don't use it actually! Thanks again to everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing **align-items: center;** to **align-items: baseline;**